# Linker issues with shared library on macOS using cmake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I have a cmake project which creates a shared library, which in turn references other libraries: openssl, zlib, libevent and libevhtp. My project is compiling/linking fine on linux (it creates the shared libraries, and also executables linked to my libraries (testcases)).

On macOS, however, I get undefined references when the library is linked:

```
[ 54%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_RAND_bytes", referenced from:
      mylib::randomStringHex(int) in util.cc.o
  "_SSL_get_ex_data", referenced from:

(...more errors)
```

Now if I add this:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${EXTERNAL_LIBS})
```

(`EXTERNAL_LIBS` contains all the externally referenced libs) it will successfully build the shared library, and I can use it/link to it and everything works.
However I cannot keep this option, because on linux I cannot link my library against `libevhtp`, because this library is not compiled with `-fPIC`.

So the question is, is it normal that on macOS the created library will always link to external libraries, or how can this be avoided? As it stands, I can either successfully build on linux or on macOS, but not both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic libraries are `linked`, thus they need to be linked with their dependencies. If you need different flags on linux and mac, just add condition to you variable:

```
if(LINUX) 
    set(EXTERNAL_LIBS ...)
endif ()
if (APPLE)
    set(EXTERNAL_LIBS ...)
endif()
```

Comment: Okay I thought about adding platform-specific options, but I wasn't sure if this was the correct way to do this. I am not so familiar with building libraries on mac, but if they're always get linked, then this will be the way to go I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator expressions instead of variables:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC
    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Darwin>:libs_only_on_osx>
    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Linux>:libs_only_on_linux>
    other_libs
)
```

This may prevent mistakes using variables.